# How do I implement an input mask with prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I would like to implement an input mask on Magento and that requires the use of the prototype javascript library.  Has anyone done this and would you be willing to share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [MaskedInput hosted at Github](http://github.com/bjartekv/MaskedInput) and see if that does what you need. I needed input masks a while back, so In lack of alternatives I ported digitalBush Masked Input Plugin for jQuery to Prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Really Easy Field Validation](http://tetlaw.id.au/view/javascript/really-easy-field-validation). You can use it by applying css classes to your input fields :)

For example:

```
<form id="some_form">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="validate-email" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new Validation('some_form');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pMask: https://github.com/greenlaw110/pMask/